# Realloc Causes Heap Corruption

Tags: c, memory-management

I am trying to write a code in C where I am facing an issue with the realloc. The code works fine at some point of time, but crashes with a Heap Corruption error during the realloc at another time.
I have pasted the structures and the function that populates the data into it. Could anyone please tell me if I am doing something wrong here.

```
typedef struct MyDataStructureStr
{
    MyDataStructureStr()
    {
        val1 = -1;
        val2 = -1;
    }

    int val1;
    int val2;
} MyDataStructureStr, *MyDataStructurePtr;

typedef struct MyStructureStr
{
    MyStructureStr()
    {
        connector = NULL;
        counter   = 0;
    }

    MyDataStructurePtr connector;
    int                counter;
}MyStructureStr, *MyStructurePtr;

static void storeData(int first, int second)
{
    if(myStruct->connector == 0)
        myStruct->connector = (MyDataStructurePtr)malloc(sizeof(MyDataStructureStr);
    else
        myStruct->connector = (MyDataStructurePtr)realloc(myStruct->connector, sizeof(MyDataStructureStr) * (myStruct->counter + 1));

    myStruct->connector[myStruct->counter].val1 = first;
    myStruct->connector[myStruct->counter].val2 = second;
    myStruct->counter++;
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're mixing C and C++, C has no constructors. Keep in mind that when you're allocating storage with malloc, your constructors are not called. Make sure  myStruct->counter and myStruct->connector gets initialized, and make sure they have the proper value when you perform realloc()

Comment: Looks like legal C to me. Isn't this how one did objects in C before C++ existed? Obviously the constructors etc. will need to be called manually.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Not enough coffee this morning. I missed the fact the 'constructor' was inside the typedef and didn't have a manually 'this' parameter etc. Apols.

Comment: my guess is that `counter` is not initialized properly since you mix C and C++ so constructors are not called.

Answer (score 5):

A few points.

1. You do not need do the `if(myStruct->connector == 0)` thing. `realloc` will allocate memory if passed a `NULL` pointer. Per the man page: *If `ptr` is `NULL`, then the call is equivalent to `malloc(size)`, for all values of size*'.
2. Your `typedef struct` functions are legal, but you should note they aren't being called.
3. I can't see where `counter` is being initialized to zero or `connector` to `NULL`. This may be because you haven't pasted the whole program.
4. I think the actual problem is that you are allocating `counter` data structures of `sizeof(MyStructureStr)`. This should be `sizeof(MyDataStructureStr)` if I understand what you are doing. This may be the cause of the heap corruption but without a full program it's hard to tell.
5. Something else in the program (that you haven't pasted) may be corrupting the heap.
6. `valgrind` is the best way to debug this sort of problem

Comment: That's why `Foo` and `Bar` are better names than `MyStructureStrType` and `MyStructureTypeStr` and `MyTypedDataStructure` when you're creating your representative test case...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Abligh. There is another function which creates an instance of the structure and in the same function, I am initializing the counter and connector. I am using the MyDataStructureStr for allocation and it was typing mistake that I have rectified it.